# Review count keeps increasing

Tags: bug

I've was given the access moderator tools privilege (on Astronomy SE, not Meta) and I've found the review count keeps increasing.

I've cleared outstanding tasks on my list a couple of time now, but the count display (orange box, white number) keeps going up and when I click it after clearing tasks there is nothing to do (the detailed review and tools page shows zero counts).

I cannot find an explanation for this, so I'm presuming it's a bug, but maybe some of you know if it is or is not.

EDIT :

I note this has occurred elsewhere on SE but also on a Beta site.  So this seems to be a Beta site issue.  As it was referred to as being related to caching perhaps it's as simple as Beta sites not having caches updated as frequently.

Comment: See: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/844/58

Comment: @called2voyage Appreciate the response, thank you.  That looks like my problem alright.

Comment: I have this problem from time to time as well.